# best way to optimize "SELECT datetime" from STRING

Tags: mysql, datetime

from database original I have many COLUMNS in varchar (string).

then I have this DataBase:

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


CREATE TABLE `pruebas` (
`id` mediumint(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`R` varchar(18) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `pruebas` (`id`, `R`) VALUES
(1, '1603892188.033'),
(2, '1603892188.473'),
(3, '1603892188.613'),
(4, '1603892188.653'),
(5, '1603892188.688'),
(6, '1603892188.703'),
(7, '1603892188.713'),
(8, '1603892188.733'),
(9, '1603892188.753'),
(10, '1603892188.783'),
(11, '1603892188.814'),
(12, '1603892188.839'),
(13, '1603892188.855'),
(14, '1603892188.878'),
(15, '1603892188.903'),
(16, '1603892188.923'),
(17, '1603892188.953'),
(18, '1603892188.973');

ALTER TABLE `pruebas`
ADD UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `pruebas`
MODIFY `id` mediumint(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=107;
COMMIT;
```

and I need recovery the DATETIME from each row WITH miliseconds.

Really I need use FOUR functions over each row to recovery the info datetime WITH microseconds?
(I have millions of rows).

My QUERY maybe obtuse is:

`SELECT id, CONCAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(R, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), '.', SUBSTRING_INDEX(R, '.', -1)) FROM pruebas`

Thanks by your lesson.

maybe other method to get datetime info?

Comment: That is a pro level username `;-)`

Answer (score 1):

This (https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wm9iQFfbZFYZa4LLXCLFHf/2)

```
SELECT id, FROM_UNIXTIME(R) dt FROM pruebas
```

works for me in any MySQL version 5.6.4 and above, to convert your millisecond-precision UNIX timestamps to MySQL `TIMESTAMP` data.

The results of this display are formatted like so.

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.ffffff
```

where the number of seconds is represented as a fractional decimal number, like `48.384000`. That (obvs) means 48 seconds plus 384 milliseconds (per the USA convention of using `.` as the decimal point). It's a number.

In this formatted timestamp:   `2020-10-28 14:22:24.000000`. the value is 24.0. That is, a zero fractional part. That explains the "crazy" zeros.

`DATE_FORMAT()` might be able to help you format that timestamp in a more visually appealing way. For example you might only show 3 digits (milliseconds) after the decimal point.

Comment: When ROW = 1603894944 QUERY `SELECT id, FROM_UNIXTIME(R) dt FROM pruebas` return `2020-10-28 09:22:24.1603894944` and my obtuse CONCAT return `2020-10-28 09:22:24.000000`. Is possible fixed this? The correct will do `2020-10-28 09:22:24`

Comment: I added that to the db-fiddle at https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wm9iQFfbZFYZa4LLXCLFHf/2 It doesn't give that wacky result for me. What version of MySQL do you use?

Comment: Tanks @O.Jones, I was go to https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wm9iQFfbZFYZa4LLXCLFHf/2 and run the QUERY `SELECT id, FROM_UNIXTIME(R) dt FROM pruebas ORDER BY id DESC` you can see "creazy" zeros in row #19